# Processing unnamed optional include file parameters in Progress

Tags: parameters, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to add a simple `IF` statement to my `include .i`-file to handle optional `unnamed parameters`:

**message.i:**

```
/*
    - {1}: Message.
    - {2}: OPTIONAL Sender name
*/
&IF DEFINED({2}) <> 0 &THEN
    {2} = "Unknown sender".
&ENDIF.
MESSAGE "{2}" + ": " + "{1}" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

**test.p:**

```
{message.i "hello world" }
// Should output "Unknown sender: hello world".
// Does not compile.

{message.i "hello world" "Michael" }
// Should output "Michael: hello world".
```

In this version, the `message.i` will throw error if the second parameter is missing.

I want to use `unnamed parameters` and avoid the parameter naming.

How I can fix the code to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the second parameter is empty :

**message.i**

```swift
&IF "{2}" <> "" &THEN
    MESSAGE "{2}" + ": " + "{1}" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
&ELSE
    MESSAGE "Unknown sender" + ": " + "{1}" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
&ENDIF.
```

[AblDojo example](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=651550b720add51d93a67a48)

Comment: Ah, I was so close getting it to work :) Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use an intermediate preprocessor to grab the unnamed parameter:

```
&if '{2}' > '' &then
   &scoped sender {2}
&else
   &scoped sender Unknown sender
&endif

message '{&sender}: {1}' view-as alert-box.
```

Watch it run at… drat, ABLDojo share and copy to clipboard does not work on an iPad.

Comment: This will come handy also, thank you very much!